# ssh on cygwin (win10): read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty:

Tags: ssh, cygwin

Executing ssh on cygwin under windows 10 recently started failing, after many years of stable logins.  The relevant output from ssh under a mintty from Xwindows:

```
%  ssh -tt -vvv <user@host>
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: failed to open file:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
debug3: spawning /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass
CreateProcessW failed error:2
ssh_askpass: posix_spawn: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

The special file /dev/tty is there:

```
% ls -la /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 jpmattia None 5, 0 May 22 15:04 /dev/tty
```

I updated Cygwin to make sure all the binaries were the latest.  Also windows updated itself earlier this week.

I'm a little baffled as to what might be going on.  Clues gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Documenting my solution in case anyone else has the problem:  It appears that a Windows version of OpenSSH was introduced in the 2018 spring update, and it is being called instead of Cygwin's ssh.  (See e.g. https://www.zdnet.com/article/openssh-arrives-in-windows-10-spring-update/)

```
% which ssh
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh
```

The reason for the sudden problem with ssh is that the cygwin PATH has /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32 ahead of /usr/bin/.  Or at least, mine did.

So the issue is solved by calling /usr/bin/ssh explicitly.  (Reordering the PATH is also a possible solution, but not for my environment.)

Comment: /usr/bin does not include `ssh` on my fresh installation of Cygwin :(

Comment: Good point:  My cygwin ssh probably came in with the openssl package from the Cygwin installer.

Comment: Cygwin has an openssh package that must be installed to get the ssh client and ssh client tools.

Comment: As other comments have hinted at, you must also install `openssh`, as it is **not** installed by default.

Comment: if you install openssh (by re-running cygwin installer and selecting the openssh package), "which ssh" command should switch to show "usr/bin/ssh" instead of "cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/..." (without any additional manual path reordering)

Comment: p.s. If you need cygwin's usr/bin/ssh to use your original windows ~\.ssh\config, go to C:\cygwin64\etc\nsswitch.conf and set `db_home: /%H`

Comment: I had the same problem when /usr/bin/ssh was not executable after a move from C to D. Worth mentioning since the error message is so obscure.

Comment: This helped a bit. I am using WSL and was having similar issues, forcing git for windows to use the ssh using `set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="C:/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh"` fixed the issue, might be different for cygwin though. Maybe cygwin needs the git's version of ssh so changing it to the other path will work for you, but for CMD+WSL2 I needed the OpenSSH version instead.

Answer (score 3):

If A fresh install of cygwin and having the sames issues, make sure to select openssh packages as part of the installation

The ssh client come with windows 10 only can be used via cmd.exe not cygwin terminal